# how to iterate through a select object array

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've a few select's with a array as the name attrib.
This select can have multiple different values in different parts of the html, so i want to iterate through the values of the stored items in the name array.

i've google for a few time and didn't find a good answer (also here in stack...), but does anybody know how can i iterate through the values of the select array with jquery if possible or js if not?
I try this but did not work

Jquery code :

```
// i get the name of the select correctly
var itemName = $(this).find("select#selectToONE").attr("name");

// try to iterate through the values when the array grows... not work
$("select[@name='"+itemName+"[]']").each(function() { alert($(this).val());} );
```

Here some html code maybe inside in one TR,TD :

```
<select name="To[itemsONE][]" id="selectToONE"> 
<option>....</option>
<option>....</option>
</select>
```

Other select inside other TR,TD

```
<select name="To[itemsONE][]" id="selectToONE">
<option>....</option>
<option>....</option>
</select>
```

Thanks.

Comment: This how i solve this :=> 
    var elem = $('select[id="selectToONE"]')
               .each(function(i,val){
                     alert($(this).val());
               });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all options you need:

```
$("select[name='"+itemName+"[]'] option").each(function(i,o){
  alert(o.value);
});
```

**UPDATE**

to iterate over an array created from *name* attribute of the particular *select*

```
var itemName = $("#selectToONE").attr("name"); // You have a string here 'To[itemsONE][]'
var s        = itemName.substring(itemName.indexOf('[')); //[itemsONE][]
```

Now it is problem here to make it work if *itemsONE* **IS** name of the variable or function use

```
var array = eval(s); //and iterate it in classic for loop
```

if it is **NOT** name of the variable, you will need also to rename the SELECT to something like this

```
<select name="To['itemsONE'][]" ...
```

Any other solution involves manualy parsing that SELECT's name by predefined pattern or regular expression

Comment: i don't want the options to be listed. I want the values of the array as i said in my question.

Comment: Its quite unclear. Which array and when do you want to iterate?

Comment: i reedited my question, maybe more clear now... i can have multiple select's with a name such as above wich stores values of the different options selected at different parts of the html...

Comment: What did you pass to the eval? You need "['itemsONE'][]"

Comment: yes, that's what the indexOf extracts to eval it, it extracts all ok.. but it reports an error evaluating it. Anyway i've solve this and in a few hours i'll post the answer (now on comment above) :). Thanks for your comments @Jan Pfeifer

Answer (score 0):

To match an attribute value in CSS, you don’t use the `@` character:

```
$("select[name='"+itemName+"[]']")
```

Comment: Oh, you’re looking for the `option` elements inside the select: `$("select[name='"+itemName+"[]'] option")`, then.

Comment: nope, i want the values of the array in the name attrib. I can have multiple similar select's each of them with different values

Comment: @dyoser “Values of the array in the name attribute?” You’re still not making sense, I’m afraid.

Comment: here the name of the select act as an array with values of the options. You can see this too with checkboxes array, or somewhat that you can have a list of checkboxes and send it as an array or parse it...